# PHP-FPM NGinx Pthreads Linux installation

Tags: multithreading, file-upload, pthreads, php

I'm trying to achieve multiple upload functionality (upload to multiple places at once).
I successfully achieved this on windows (XAMPP + PThreads DLL's) but when installing PHP-FPM+php-pecl-pthreads.x86_64, and extending the Thread class i'm getting the error:

```
include(Thread.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

i tried adding all pthreads.so related to the php.ini:

```
/usr/lib64/php/modules/pthreads.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pthreads.so
/usr/lib64/libpthread.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libmudflapth.so
/lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
```

but i'm getting

```
undefined symbol: core_globals_id in Unknown on line 0
```

on my phpinfo i see thread safety is disabled.

Did anyone achieve this functionality and can shed some light on how to upload to multiple places at once / installing pthreads successfully on linux.

thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debian/ubuntu

1. download php source (make sure you have deb-src)

> `apt-get source php5`

2. go to that dir

> `cd php5*`

3. go to ext dir

> `cd ext`

4. download pthreads

> `git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.git`

5. rebuild the configure settings

> `cd .. && ./buildconf --force`

6. ensure you have pthreads in configure options

> `./configure --help | grep pthre`

7. run configure (change the paths as appropriate for your setup)

> `./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-pthreads --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --enable-fpm`

8. visit [this](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.install.php) for more info about user/group specific options if you need them.

> `make -j2`
>
> `make -j2 install`

9. Now you will have php compiled with pthreads support. Verify this:

> `php -m | grep pthreads`

10. Make init script

> `copy sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm /etc/init.d/php-fpm`

11. change `user` and `group` to the username which nginx use in `/etc/init.d/php-fpm`.

> `service nginx restart`

12. Go to your nginx public foolder

> `cd <your-nginx-public-folder>`

13. `touch phpinfo.php && echo "<?php phpinfo();" >> phpinfo.php`
14. go to your browser and search for pthreads in `http://<your url>/phpinfo.php` just created php file

Comment: just in case anyone else is trying to achieve the same thing - i succeeded to upload multiple files using guzzle...probably the easier solution
But thx!